# How do I develop a non-UI client-side GWT library?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.4

I wish to write a shared library to be used in various GWT applications. The shared library will leverage GWT APIs and should not be able to use non-emulated Java classes.

Two questions:

- Is there a plugin for Eclipse that will let me use GWT APIs and flag if I use a non-emulated class (but will simply build a compliant jar rather than a war)? (*I know that the standard plugin does this when working in the 'client' area, I just want the same behaviour for the entire source tree)*
- If not, is there a Maven/Ant plugin that will help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a GWT library, you have to include a GWT module (`*.gwt.xml` file) and the `*.java` files in your `*.jar` (or in a distinct JAR if you prefer).

AFAIK, the Google Plugin for Eclipse uses the information from the `*.gwt.xml` files, the `client` subpackage is not hard-coded; so you should be able to use it the same way as with a GWT application.

Finally, you can call the GWT compiler with the argument `-validateOnly` to check that your GWT module uses only translatable classes.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that you can't develop a gwt shared library and pack it into a jar file. Gwt require access to all source code when compiling files. It can't read class files at all. Or have I misunderstood what you are trying to do?